# Can i see how much internet data has been download by user if i use Active directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, dhcp

IF i use active directory for users to log in my domain and that server is the DHCP server. Can i then see how much user is downloading from internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ErikA said.

Also, if you're only worried about internet traffic, try installing a proxy server (it can be transparent, so appears to work the same as a normal NAT box) and setting your DHCP server to point to it as a gateway.

Something like Squid, or ISA (if you have the budget) will give you reporting on which IPs (or users) have use how much traffic, where it went, and when it was used.

A software solution like [PFSense](http://www.pfsense.org/) with the Squid proxy and LightSquid reporting plugins would be perfect, easy to set up and deploy.

Comment: Agreed about pfsense - great platform. Also, it's true that a web proxy will provide accounting for web traffic. It won't, however, provide data on other types of internet traffic. P2P, bittorrent, etc. come to mind.

Comment: True that... only :80 traffic...

Comment: WHich thing should i install first squid proxy then lightsquid and then Pfsense

Comment: Install pfsense on a spare PC (with two NICs), throw it on your network in place of the current router and then install the plugins Farseeker mentioned.

Comment: Can't i install pfsense on window 2008

Comment: No. PFSense is a dedicated FreeBSD distribution. What you COULD do, is install Hyper-V or VMWare Server and deploy PFSense into that. But as ErikA mentioned, it will only collect statistics for traffic that comes through a web browser, not torrent, newsgroups, P2P, etc

Comment: To clarify, for pfsense to be of any use for you, it needs to be put in place between your network and your internet connection.

Comment: I think web will be sufficient for me initially. But if install pfsense in VM then do i need two LAN cards as Erika mentioned

Comment: i have one modem--router---computer.  SO i install pfsense in VM what do i have to do to make it work

Comment: What you will need to do is give your VM two virtual network cards. They can both be assigned to the same physical card if you like. What you do then is assign one virtual adapter to be your WAN, and one to be your LAN. It will then route traffic in and out of the same physical card, but because the VM has two nics it can log the traffic between them. Then you need to point all of your Default Gateways to the PFSense VM.

Comment: It might be best if you move the modem/router onto a different subnet (if it's 192.168.0.1, move it to 192.168.1.1) or else you will run into routing issues on the PFSense box, because it will try to route traffic out through the LAN interface as well.

Comment: WOW thats great i definitely want to try that but few thigns i would like to know

1)Suppose i installed PFsense on VM. then how to assign WAN on Lan card1 and LAN on LAN card2......
2)I can assign the default gateway to that pfsense card in DHCP server on window 2008 (VM).......
3)My current router ip is 10.0.11.1 . I didn't understand that part of changing subnet because internet to pfsense is coming from router

......

It will be good if you can write it in your post as this very good info

Comment: Hmm, to be honest I think this discusison has probably gone more complex than commenting will allow to make sense of, what I recommend is just downloading it, installing it in a VM with two network cards, and when you get stuck, read the PFSense manual or failing that, ask a question here. PFSense is easy to set up and it will give you the option to assign the WAN and LAN interfaces when you first set it up

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

For that type of information, you'll need to either do some sort of accounting on the user's workstation or (more likely) your router/gateway. Depending on the capabilities of your switchgear, you can use SNMP to poll interface in/out data from your switches. Of course this assumes that you know what port each user is connected to.

Also - Active Directory nor DHCP really have anything to do with this. Once your clients get their lease from the DHCP server, its job is done. It has nothing to do with network traffic from that point on.

Answer (score 0):

Others have suggested pfSense, and there's nothing wrong with pfSense, but almost any enterprise class gateway these days has the ability to link to an AD and work as a proxy.  You can even apply different rules to different AD users or groups.

Comment: If you have an enterprise class router then you can use netflow which would be a better solution

Comment: What type of enterprise class gateway u r talking about.e,g